# Android: programmatically making full screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I wanted to make full screen on button click and make it back to normal on pressing back button.

In Android studio

Answer (score 0):

In OnCreate()

```
 Button x = findViewById(R.id.button);
       x.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
             setContentView(R.layout.mainActivity);
          }
       });
```

Now you need exit from full screen use this code :

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN); ActivitiesCurrentContentView.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Let me try this .....

Answer (score -1):

You can do it programmatically

```
    public class ActivityName extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // remove title
    Button x = findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
       x.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
             setContentView(R.layout.main);
          }
       });
}
}
```

Comment: Yap this is okay, but how to exit full screen

Comment: To exit full screen  set this code in exit button click method getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
ActivitiesCurrentContentView.requestLayout();

Comment: Ty.... Let me try

Comment: This gives error......

Comment: @Kàrthîkßàlàkrìshña which type of error ???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54583904/9161788